# How can I get a specific value in this PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm setting up a Cloudinary listing of uploaded videos and I want to get the metadata of that video.

I have a `print_r($result)`:

```
<pre>
Cloudinary\Api\Response Object
(
    [rate_limit_reset_at] => 123123123
    [rate_limit_allowed] => 123
    [rate_limit_remaining] => 123
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [public_id] => dog
            [format] => mp4
            [version] => 123123123
            [resource_type] => video
            [type] => upload
            [created_at] => 2019-07-29T07:32:50Z
            [bytes] => 123123
            [width] => 321
            [height] => 456
            [backup] => 1
            [access_mode] => public
            [url] => http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/video/upload/dog.mp4
            [secure_url] => https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/video/upload/dog.mp4
            [next_cursor] => 123123123
            [derived] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [transformation] => /jpg
                            [format] => jpg
                            [bytes] => 86438
                            [id] => 123123123
                            [url] => http://res.cloudinary.com//demo/video/upload/dog.jpg
                            [secure_url] => https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/video/upload/dog.mp4
                            [extension] => jpg
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [transformation] => t_media_lib_thumb/jpg
                            [format] => jpg
                            [bytes] => 3293
                            [id] => 12123123
                            [url] => https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/video/upload/dog.jpg
                            [secure_url] => https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/video/upload/dog.jpg
                            [extension] => jpg
                        )

                )

        )

)
</pre>
```

I tried getting the value using this format but it says undefined index. `echo $result[4]['width']` or `echo $result['storage:ArrayObject:private']['width'];`

Comment: We can not help you if you dont write better what are your trying to get.

Comment: It's not an array. You're dumping an object. And storage is private property (not accessible from outside the object).

Comment: As the label suggests, storage:ArrayObject:private is private. Also, you are trying to use the Cloudinary\Api\Response object as an array.

Comment: I just wanted to get the metadata from my uploaded video on cloudinary, I want to get the width, height and byte size which are already in that object (I thought it was an array.) Is there any other way to get it or it's impossible since it says it's private?

Answer (score 1):

I talked to a cloudinary support ad he said that "you should be able to access the data returned within [storage:ArrayObject:private] by simply ignoring it and requesting the index that you desire directly from $result. Meaning you can use  or  and so on with the other paramters."

So basically, just removing the index solved my problem like so:

```
<?php echo $result['height']; ?> <?php echo $result['width']; ?>
```

Comment: If someone from Cloudinary sees this, can you please add this to your documentation? It took me hours to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/blob/master/src/Api/Response.php in order to better understand the object you are getting back.

Afterwards, look at the ArrayObject documentation here https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php, as your Response object extends this class. Using getArrayCopy() to transform your object into an array should be what you need.

Bear in mind that I am not familiar with the API and that there may be better options to get what you need.